# How to view date as month and year

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a date field which is `TargetDate` which I have setup as a date field in the edit box, what I need to do is change the view page so that it appears as Month and Date.  (edit and view are two different tabs on my form), edit side works perfectly, but I need some custom PHP to get this to work, any ideas?

So far I have this:

```
$month=date("F",$values["TargetDate"]);
$year=date("Y",$values["TargetDate"]);
$values["TargetDate"] = $month." ".$year;
```

But that turns the output into the following format:
2015-04-30

Where as I want it to say April 2015

Comment: Try to learn [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function in php

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code:

```
$month=date("F", strtotime($values["TargetDate"]));
$year=date("Y", strtotime($values["TargetDate"]));
$values["TargetDate"] = $month." ".$year;
```

or directly:

```
$values["TargetDate"] = date("F Y", strtotime($values["TargetDate"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
echo date('F Y', strtotime('2015-04-02'));
```

In your code it would be -

```
echo date('F Y', strtotime($values["TargetDate"]));
```